# mail sending using servlet

Tags: email, servlets, nullpointerexception, classnotfoundexception

This is my Html File:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cloud Counselage Internship Program</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #ecf0f1;
            color: #2c3e50;
            font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        header {
            background-color: #3498db;
            color: #ecf0f1;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 1em;
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            margin-bottom: 1em;
        }

        form {
         text-align:center;
            margin: 2em;
            padding: 2em;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            width: 50%; /* Adjust the width as needed */
            max-width: 600px; /* Optional: Set a maximum width */
             /* Center text within the form */
        }

        input[type="text"] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0.5em;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        button {
            background-color: #2ecc71;
            color: #ecf0f1;
            padding: 0.5em 1em;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        button:hover {
            background-color: #27ae60;
           
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Cloud Counselage Pvt. Ltd. Internship Program Enrollment Form</h1>
    </header>
    
    <form action="Serv7" method="get">
        <label for="Name1">First Name </label>
        <input type="text" id="field1" name="name1" required><br>

        <label for="Name2">Last Name </label>
        <input type="text" id="field2" name="name2" required><br>

        <label for="Gmail">Personal Email </label>
        <input type="text" id="field3" name="gmail" required><br>

        <label for="Phno">Contact No </label>
        <input type="text" id="field3" name="phno" required><br>
        <!-- Add more fields as needed -->

        <input type="submit" value=Submit>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my Servlet file with Serv8 name:

```java
package Pkg;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;
//import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
//import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
//import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

@WebServlet("/Serv8")
public class Serv8 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Serv8() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        final String user = "my mail id"; // change accordingly
        final String password = " My password for loging my google account"; // change accordingly
        String to = "rd10311031@gmail.com"; // change accordingly

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

         Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
            }
        });

        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject("JAVAMailAPI");
            message.setText("This is a simple program of sending email using JavaMail API");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Message sent successfully...");

            response.getWriter().println("<html><body>");
            response.getWriter().println("<h2>Email sent successfully to " + to + "</h2>");
            response.getWriter().println("</body></html>");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.getWriter().println("<html><body>");
            response.getWriter().println("<h2>Error sending email: " + e.getMessage() + "</h2>");
            response.getWriter().println("</body></html>");
        }
        
        
    }

    /*protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }*/
}
```

I need to this servlet should send me mail on given username, but when I run on server its shows errors `NullPointerException`, and `javax.mail.Authenticator` class not found. I added latest jar file `javax.mail.jar` file to libraries of project directory in Eclipse also.

once I run it in Eclipse console shows this error and one prompt is come that server is failed to run on localhost. my server version is compatible with my java. so here only one problem is there class not found that's why null pointer exception is coming so for that what could be solution.